# How to show progress of subrepository update?

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisehg, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I have a Mercurial repository that contains a SVN subrepository. During `hg update` Mercurial freezes during processing of `.hgsubstate` file. I understand that this is because Mercurial executes `svn` command in background that pulls correct revision of SVN.

It is very unintuitive for my users because SVN subrepository is quite big and whole looks like having a hung.

Is there a way to dump svn output during such operation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `hg -v`? That normally makes mercurial more verbose, which you would expect to pass on verbosity flags to `svn`.